# JSF Datatable update component when changing page (outside of Datatable)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.list}"
             var="q"
             styleClass="data-apresenta"
             rowIndexVar="qi" itemType="none"
             paginator="true"
             rows="1"
             id="dataL">    
</p:dataTable>

<h:outputLabel id="anyComponenteID" value="Test"/>
```

I have this test code but, how  can i update `anyComponenteID` when I paginate through primefaces datatable ?

Note :  component is outside of dataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind an ajax listener to the `page` event inside primefaces datatable, you will need to set your form to `prependId="true"` so you can reach components outside of the datatable.

The code will look like something like this:

`<p:ajax event="page" process="@this" update=":form-id:mycomponent-id"/>`

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer, because that might help other people.